# Write down the elements of the cyclic subgroups in S8 generated by α and by α^-1 respectively.

Tags: symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let S8 be the symmetric group of degree 8.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
6 8 3 7 1 4 5 2
```

Write down the elements of the cyclic subgroups in S8 generated by α and by α^(−1) respectively.

So I found a^(-1) to be

```
12345678
58367142
```

and a in disjoint form is (16475)(28)

a^(-1) in disjoint form is (15746)(28)

what do I do now?

Comment: As a starting point: the order of $\alpha$ is equal to $\operatorname{lcm}(5,2)=10$, so there are $10$ elements in your subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all any element and its inverse (in any group) generate the same subgroup, this easily follows from the fact that any subgroup which contains $\alpha$ must contain $\alpha^{-1}$ and vice versa. So you don't need to think of this as two different exercises.

Anyway, the group which is generated by one element is $\langle\alpha\rangle=\{\alpha^k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. If the order of $\alpha$ is finite and equal to $n$ then it is equal to $\{\alpha^k: 0\leq k\leq n-1\}$. So just start multiplying $\alpha$ by itself until you get the identity. This way you will get the whole subgroup $\langle\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: Maybe a bit of a dumb question. But how do I multiply alpha by itself here?

Comment: Here the operation is composition. Do you know how to multiply permutations? For example $\alpha^2=(16475)(28)(16475)(28)=(14567)$.

Comment: No, thats the part I don't get.

Comment: For example where does $\alpha^2=\alpha\circ\alpha$ map $1$? $\alpha$ maps $1\to 6$ and $6\to 4$. Hence $\alpha\circ\alpha(1)=\alpha(6)=4$. So $\alpha^2$ maps $1\to 4$. Then continue like that with other elements. It is just composition of functions. (you should try to multiply a few permutations to get used to it)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems to be working.